# Prove that $\mu ((X,Y)^n (X+1, Y+1)^m)=(n+1)(m+1)$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, computational-algebra, groebner-generators

Let $k$ be a field (if it helps, we can think $k$ algebraically closed and/or of characteristic $0$), and consider the polynomial ring $k[X,Y]$. For an ideal $I$ of $k[X,Y]$ I denote by $$\mu(I) = \min \{ n \ge 1 : \exists x_1, \dots x_n \mbox{ generators of } I\}$$
the minimum cardinality of systems of generators of $I$.

> I am interested in proving for all $n,m \ge 1$ the equality
>   $$\mu ((X,Y)^n (X+1, Y+1)^m)=(n+1)(m+1)$$

What I know:

1. $\mu((X,Y)^n) = n+1$ : I localize $k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}$ and find a lower bound $\mu((X,Y)^n) \ge n+1$ using Nakayama's lemma. On the other hand $\{X^n, X^{n-1}Y, \dots,Y^n \}$ is a system of generators of $(X,Y)^n$ formed by $n+1$ elements, so $\mu((X,Y)^n) \le n+1$.
2. Similarly I have shown $\mu((X+1, Y+1)^m)=m+1$
3. Putting together 1. and 2. I have
   $$\mu ((X,Y)^n (X+1, Y+1)^m) \le (n+1)(m+1)$$
4. Using Macaulay2 (although I know very little about this software), I found out that the formula is correct for large values of $n,m$, (if I didn't make mistakes), so I believe that it is correct.

What I don't know: everything concerning Groebner bases and stuff like that.

Please can you give me a way to prove this equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality is wrong. In your situation the correct number is $\max\{m,n\}+1$. The quickest proof is by appealing to Serre's codimension two trick. If $J\subset k[x,y]=R$ is a height two ideal, then $\mu(J)=\mu(\mathrm{Ext}^1(J,R))+1$ which in turn is same as $\mu(\mathrm{Ext}^2(R/J,R))+1$. In your case, since $(x,y)$ and $(x+1,y+1)$ are comaximal, Chinese remainder theorem will give us the estimate I said.

Just to illustrate this, let me look at the case for simplicity, where $n=m$.  Then $(x,y)=(x-y,y)$ and $(x+1,y+1)=(x-y, y+1)$. Thus, $(x,y)^n(x+1,y+1)^n=((x-y, y)(x-y,y+1) )^n=(x-y, y(y+1))^n$, which is $n+1$ generated.

This is to answer Georges comment. I will assume and it is clear that $\mu(\mathrm{Ext}^1(J,R))=\mu(\mathrm{Ext}^2(R/J,R))$. If this number is $d$, then easy homological algebra says that there exists an element $\eta\in \mathrm{Ext}^1(J,R^d)$ such that the corresponding extension, $0\to R^d\to P\to J\to 0$ has the property, when we apply $\mathrm{Hom}(*,R)$, we get a surjection $\mathrm{Hom}(R^d,R)\to \mathrm{Ext}^1(J,R)$. This implies by ext calculations that $P$ is a projective module of rank $d+1$ and since it is free (by Seshadri's theorem), $\mu(J)=d+1$.

If $J=IL$, where $I,L$ are height two comaximal ideals as in the above question, then $R/J=R/I\oplus R/L$ by Chinese remainder theorem. Thus $\mathrm{Ext}^2(R/J,R)=\mathrm{Ext}^2(R/I,R)\oplus \mathrm{Ext}^2(R/L,R)$. Since $I,L$ are comaximal, easy to check that $\mu(\mathrm{Ext}^2(R/J,R))=\max\{ \mu(\mathrm{Ext}^2(R/I,R)),\mu(\mathrm{Ext}^2(R/L,R))\}$.

Finally, for the above question, writing $u=x-y$, I claim the ideal in question is generated by (assuming say $n\geq m$) the following. $u^ky^{n-k}$ for $n\geq k\geq m$ and $u^ky^{n-k}(y+1)^{m-k}$ for $0\leq k<m$. These are contained in the given ideal is obvious and it is equal can be checked by inverting $y$ and $y+1$.

Comment: Dear Mohan, where do these mysterious  codimension two trick and calculations come from?

Comment: Dear Georges Elencwajg, the codimension two trick of course is the starting point of Serre's conjecture etc. for freeness of projective modules over polynomial rings. In the particular case of the above question, it is easier to do things by hand, though it may look mysterious.

Comment: Dear Mohan, thank you for your comment but I'm still baffled  since there seems to be no free nor projective module in sight . I would be very grateful if you would be so kind as to enrich  your first section by some explicit  computations with the $Ext$ functor [done by *your* hand :-)] , which might also be of help to other similarly puzzled users. That said, your last computation is already very neat: bravo!

Comment: Dear Georges Elencwajg, I have added some more details in the answer.

Comment: Dear Mohan that's fantastic! Thanks and a well-deserved +1, of course.